# How do I differ proxy server error from target server failure?

Tags: c#, .net, http, proxy, web-scraping

I'm writing scraper, which eventualy gets blocked when too many request come from the same IP, thus I'm using proxy servers after some time.

The question is: Is there any possibility to identify if error/exception raised on proxy server or target server? If the proxy server goes offline/is not reliable/timeouts offten, I need to identyfy it and delete it from list of servers I store internally and I need to use another one.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: You could try a different target like Google or ping it.

Comment: Oh like if I get error, p.e. Timeout, I try to acces some server which is sure to respond with the same proxy?
Damn, the simpliest solutions are usually the best, thanks!

Comment: Yup. If that works out let me know and I will slap it up as an answer so this doesn't go unanswered.